# sum of each element in all 2x2 submatrices from a matrix

Tags: haskell, matrix

I need to get a list if the sum of each 2x2 submatrix in a matrix with even rows and cols.

For example, say that we have a 4x4 matrix (1); the function should compute it like the following (**I would just like to note that the given matrix can be any nxm matrix where n and m are even**):

```
(1): [ [1,  2, 3, 4],
       [5,  6, 7, 8],
       [9, 10,11,12],
       [13,14,15,16] ]

sum2x2 of (1):
    1. 1+2+5+6    = 14
    2. 3+4+7+8    = 22
    3. 9+10+13+14 = 46
    .
    .


result: [14, 22, 46, ...]
```

I want to use [Data.Matrix](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html) and `submatrix` to create this list. And the function should have the following pattern:

```
sum2x2 :: Matrix Double -> [Double]
```

I have begun writing this function, but I don't know how to proceed from here:

```
sum2x2 :: Matrix Double -> [Double]
sum2x2 m = if even (ncols m) && even (nrows m)
  then what?
  else error "sum2x2 takes only even matrices"
```

`submatrix` works like the following:

```
-- | /O(1)/. Extract a submatrix given row and column limits.
--   Example:
--
-- >                   ( 1 2 3 )
-- >                   ( 4 5 6 )   ( 2 3 )
-- > submatrix 1 2 2 3 ( 7 8 9 ) = ( 5 6 )
submatrix :: Int    -- ^ Starting row
          -> Int -- ^ Ending row
          -> Int    -- ^ Starting column
          -> Int -- ^ Ending column
          -> Matrix a
          -> Matrix a
```

So, I have the concept. How do I implement this in Haskell using list comprehension?

Comment: `Data.Matrix` package includes nice [Splitting Blocks](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html#g:8) functionalities like `submatrix`. They are very handy tools for this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about just using the `sum` function for the matrix since it's the instance of [Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#t:Foldable)?

```
import Data.Matrix

sum2x2 :: Matrix Double -> Double
sum2x2 m = if even (ncols m) && even (nrows m)
  then sum m
  else error "sum2x2 takes only even matrices"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ sum2x2 (fromList 2 2 [1..])
```

This example creates a matrix `((1, 2), (3, 4))` and returns the sum `10`. I guess, the type of `sum2x2` should be `sum2x2 :: Matrix Double -> Double` instead of `sum2x2 :: Matrix Double -> [Double]`

You might also find [splitBlocks](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.5.0/docs/Data-Matrix.html#v:splitBlocks) functions usefull.

```
splitBlocks 2 2 matrix4x4
```

Creates a tuple of type `(Matrix a, Matrix a, Matrix a, Matrix a)`, which are the matrices you're looking for.

If the problem is to convert any `M x N` (certainly with even `M`s and `N`s) matrix to a list of `2 x 2` matrices, then the following implementation might be helpful:

```
to2x2Martices m =
  [submatrix x1 x2 y1 y2 m | (x1, x2) <- rawPairs, (y1, y2) <- columnPairs]
  where
    pairs [] = []
    pairs (x:y:xs) = (x, y) : pairs xs

    rawPairs = pairs [1..(nrows m)]
    columnPairs = pairs [1..(ncols m)]
```

The logic is to iterate every pair in rows and every pair in columns and get the `2 x 2` matrix for these pairs.

It transforms the following matrix:

```
(  1  2  3  4 )
(  5  6  7  8 )
(  9 10 11 12 )
( 13 14 15 16 )
```

Into the following list:

```
[(  1  2 )
(  5  6 )
,(  3  4 )
(  7  8 )
,(  9 10 )
( 13 14 )
,( 11 12 )
( 15 16 )
]
```

Thus, you can just map over the list and get sum for every element.

```
map sum $ to2x2Martices (fromList 4 4 [1..])
```

evaluates to `[14,22,46,54]`

Comment: But the OP wants to calculate the sum of every 2x2 **sub**matrix.

Comment: Exactly, I know that I can easily get the sum of one 2x2 submatrix from a nxm matrix where n and m are even, but how to get a list of sums for each of the 2x2 submatrices in the given matrix? How can I use splitBlocks in a way so that for a nxm matrix, I get a list of all the 2x2 submatrices within the matrix?

Comment: this is the way to go, did not know about splitBlocks, and seems very handy. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One other way of doing this job would be to use the `submatrix` function of type `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Matrix a -> Matrix a` where the first 4 parameters of `Int` type are starting row, ending row, starting column, ending column.

```
import Data.Matrix
subsums :: Matrix Int -> [Int]
subsums m = let subs = map (\(x,y) -> (x,x+1,y,y+1)) $ (,) <$> [1,3..nrows m] <*> [1,3..ncols m]
            in  map (\(rs, re, cs, ce) -> sum (submatrix rs re cs ce m)) subs

*Main> subsums . fromLists $ [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12], [13,14,15,16]]
[14,22,46,54]
```